# Clone (and extend) gitlab-ci-runner OR use omnibus runner and call docker image

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Context: we test R packages within a docker image having the necessary environment and additionally pulling in some other packages (from our gitlab repo using ssh-keys supplied to the docker image).

As gitlab-ci-runner is docker based I see two possibilities:

1. clone existing gitlab-ci-runner (e.g. [this](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab-ci-runner) but more likely from scratch as we need a wheezy base). Then extend this clone with the necessary R environment. The test commands in Jobs -> Script are easy.
2. use a standard omnibus gitlab-ci-runner installation and call our (nested) docker image in Jobs -> Script. It's a bit more involved but perfectly doable.

Currently I have no idea which approach is preferable.

Someone said, it's more professional to use one's own runner. On the other side it seems more standard to go with to officially recommended omnibus runner installer.

Answer (score 0):

Sytse answered in [google groups](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gitlabhq/JUpajvj23KE/TYIJi3Iw5OMJ):

"Can you take your docker image and add any runner from 
https://about.gitlab.com/gitlab-ci/#gitlab-runner to it and save that 
as a new image?"